# GA transactions per transactionid always 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

GA transactions per transactionid always 4 when using the api.

Google Dimensions: ga:transactionid, ga:channelGrouping
Metrices: ga:transactions

The result set shows lower number of transactionids and every transactionid appear to have had 4 transactions which is not possible

Answer (score 0):

It could be if sampling is applied to your report.